# Android SDK Manager and AVD Manager won't run

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

I'm running into a large handful of problems with using the Android SDK and AVD Managers.  Neither one of them will run be running the executables in the android-sdk directory or from Eclipse.

However, I can run the SDK Manager by running android.bat from a command prompt.  From there I can get to the AVD manager from the Tools menu.  However, this is less than optimal.

I'm running Windows XP on a 32-bit platform.  I'm running Java 1.6 and I have the Android SDK 20.0.3 installed.  In Eclipse I'm using 4.2 with the latest Android plugins installed.

From past research I've verified that find_java is actually finding the right java.

There was a one time instance in which I could launch the SDK Manager from Eclipse, but not from the executable.  And up until I added a couple of SDK versions I could run the AVD Manager from Eclipse.

Thoughts?

Comment: Well, what are the actual problems? Error messages, etc?

Comment: That's the thing.  I don't get any error messages.  At most I'll get the famous command window that briefly opens and closes.

Even in Eclipse it will bring up the Progress dialog, which runs it's course but no window is opened.  And there is no output in the Eclipse Console window.

Comment: I'm guessing that you change the default location where Android Studio is installed.  See my SO question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272258/avd-manager-on-android-studio-1-5-1-and-install-to-a-custom-location-emulator-wo?noredirect=1#comment58256034_35272258

Answer (score 0):

Delete `~/.android` and run it again.  (Worked for me.)